# Dynamic size in jscolor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscolor

I use jscolor on my website and it works fine, but it should be responsive.

I've found a way to set width and hight (see [jscolor.com](http://jscolor.com/examples)):

```html
<input type="text" class="jscolor {width:365, height:225, position:'center'} ">
```

Is it possible to make it responsive by add some css for example?
I haven't found any kind of documentation or something like this.

PS: Sorry for bad English. I'm a newbie in html, css, javascript & co and I hope my question is not to idiotic.

Comment: What do you mean by "be responsive"?

Comment: I want to have a smaller color picker for smartphones and a bigger for pc and tablets. The size should be dynamic like a button with css-style width 100% for example.